# Reordering bootstrap elements between "stacks"/columns without javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible to:

from this state, after deleting 3

[image]

have this:

[image]

without custom **javascript**? (Word "without" is most important here). 
CSS, html etc can be used.

This is playground code:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="col-md-4  rainbow1">
    <h1>1</h1>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4  rainbow2">
    <h1>4</h1>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4  rainbow3">
    <h1>7</h1>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4  rainbow1">
    <h1>2</h1>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4  rainbow2">
    <h1>5</h1>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4  rainbow3">
    <h1>8</h1>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4  rainbow1">
    <h1>3</h1>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4  rainbow2">
    <h1>6</h1>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4  rainbow3">
    <h1>9</h1>
</div>
```

```
    .rainbow1{
    color:darkblue !important;
    border:solid;
}
.rainbow2{
    color:#ff0000 !important ;
    border:solid;
}

.rainbow3{
    color:#ffd800 !important;
    border:solid;
}

.rainbow4{
    color:#4cff00 !important;
    border:solid;
}

.rainbow5{
    color:#0094ff !important;
}

.rainbow6{
    color:#b5ac78 !important;
    border:solid;
}

.rainbow7{
    color:#000000 !important;
    border:solid;
}
.rainbow8{
    color:#ff00dc !important;
    border:solid;
}

.rainbow9{
    color:#b6ff00 !important;
    border:solid;
}

.rainbow10{
    color:#ff006e !important;
    border:solid;
}
```

Comment: i think `float:left` may help

Comment: @AkramLazkanee the class `col-*-*` already is floated left

Comment: Would recommend checking out flexbox to achieve the desired result. Wouldn't work with bootstrap columns though. Here's a good starting point: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you can achieve this with CSS3 columns without bootstrap.

Complimentary fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/4ajv8fn7/4/

> Note: The JS in the fiddle is just a helper so you can click on the cells to remove them :)

source & more info about browser support: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="cell rainbow1">
    <h1>1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="cell  rainbow1">
    <h1>2</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="cell  rainbow1">
    <h1>3</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="cell rainbow2">
    <h1>4</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="cell rainbow2">
    <h1>5</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="cell  rainbow2">
    <h1>6</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="cell rainbow3">
    <h1>7</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="cell rainbow3">
    <h1>8</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="cell rainbow3">
    <h1>9</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.rainbow1 {
  color: darkblue !important;
  border: solid;
  padding: 1px;
}

.rainbow2 {
  color: #ff0000 !important;
  border: solid;
  padding: 1px;
}

.rainbow3 {
  color: #ffd800 !important;
  border: solid;
  padding: 1px;
}

.cell {
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}

.parent {
  -webkit-columns: 3;
  -moz-columns: 3;
  columns: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 0;
  -moz-column-gap: 0;
  column-gap: 0;
  padding: 1px;
}
```

Comment: I was even able to add bootstrap classes to it so it helped worked as mentioned. Thank you